# Which type of t-test to perform?

Tags: r, t-test

Ques. An experiment is conducted to study the hybrid seed production of bottle gourd
under open field conditions. The main aim of the investigation is to compare
natural pollination and hand pollination. The data are collected on 10 randomly
selected plants from each of natural pollination and hand pollination. The data
are collected on fruit weight (kg), seed yield/plant (g) and seedling length (cm).

a. Is the overall population of Seed yield/plant (g) equals to 200?
b. Test whether the natural pollination and hand pollination under open field
conditions are equally effective or are significantly different.

Do I have to perform separate t-tests for both part (a) and (b) ?
Or a single test can give solution to both parts ?
Just need a clarity as to which type of test I have to perform.

Answer (score 0):

for a, perform 1-sample T-test as given 1 static value (2020) which is the population mean  has to compare with  1 continuous variable Seed yield/plant (g)

for b, perform 2 Sample T-test (Independent) for 1 categorical variable(Group) and 1 continuous variable (No_of_Fruit_Set(45days))

Answer (score 0):

You have three treatments effects which you have to compare between  natural pollination and hand pollination namely

1. fruit weight (kg), (FW)
2. Seed yield/plant (g) (SY) and
3. Seedling length (cm) (SL).
   Find Mean and SD for each of the above variables for both the treatment conditions namely Natural Pollination (NP) and Hand Pollination (HP).
   Carry out t-independent test for FW, SY and SL between NP and HP.
   This will show the effectiveness of hand pollination vs natural pollination with respect to FW, SY AND SL.
   It is not necessary that all the three effects will show the significance differences between NP and HP.
   To answer a) you have to carry out single mean test separately for NP and HP.